# Multiple plots in single image in gonum/plot

Tags: go, gonum

Is it possible to combine multiple plots in a single image in gonum/plot?
They should have their own axes. Is it possible to stack them vertically, horizontally or probably in a grid?

In matplotlib it would look like this.
[image: Subplots]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've tried and explaining specifically what was wrong with the result.

Comment: @Adrian, I'm asking if library has specific feature. It is not documented but probably there is a way to do it. I have no problem with my code. So I guess your suggestion is inappropriate here.

Comment: @IgorMikushkin: I would try the gonum mailing before SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [plot.Align](https://godoc.org/gonum.org/v1/plot#Align).

Also have a look at the example code I posted to your issue [Multiple line plots sharing abscissas axis in gonum/plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557438/multiple-line-plots-sharing-abscissas-axis-in-gonum-plot). The code is applicable to this issue as well.